# pandas DataFrameで座標が入れ子になっているデータセットの分割

Tags: python, pandas, 行列, dataframe

複数の座標から線分の組合せパターンを抽出した後、各線分と一つ一つの座標との組み合わせを一つの行にまとめたデータセットを作成したいです。
（その後、行ごとに線分と座標の関係を計算することが目的です）

例えば３つの座標の場合、重複をまったく考慮せずにすべての組合わせを考える場合、
線分の組合わせは３＊３、これに対してそれぞれの線分に各座標との組み合わせ＊３の、
３＊３＊３の２７パターンができるかと存じます。

各パターンを一つの行に並べ、行ごとにひとつひとつの数値を使って線分と座標の関係を色々と計算したいです。

【こうしたいです】

```
     Ax Ay  Bx  By  Cx  Cy
0   [1] [1]  [1] [1]  [1] [1]　←行毎に別途計算を行うことが目的です
1   [1] [1]  [1] [1]  [2] [2]
2   [1] [1]  [1] [1]  [3] [3]
3   [1] [1]  [2] [2]  [1] [1]
4   [1] [1]  [2] [2]  [2] [2]
5   [1] [1]  [2] [2]  [3] [3]
6   [1] [1]  [3] [3]  [1] [1]
7   [1] [1]  [3] [3]  [2] [2]
8   [1] [1]  [3] [3]  [3] [3]
9   [2] [2]  [1] [1]  [1] [1]
10  [2] [2]  [1] [1]  [2] [2]
11  [2] [2]  [1] [1]  [3] [3]
12  [2] [2]  [2] [2]  [1] [1]
13  [2] [2]  [2] [2]  [2] [2]
14  [2] [2]  [2] [2]  [3] [3]
15  [2] [2]  [3] [3]  [1] [1]
16  [2] [2]  [3] [3]  [2] [2]
17  [2] [2]  [3] [3]  [3] [3]
18  [3] [3]  [1] [1]  [1] [1]
19  [3] [3]  [1] [1]  [2] [2]
20  [3] [3]  [1] [1]  [3] [3]
21  [3] [3]  [2] [2]  [1] [1]
22  [3] [3]  [2] [2]  [2] [2]
23  [3] [3]  [2] [2]  [3] [3]
24  [3] [3]  [3] [3]  [1] [1]
25  [3] [3]  [3] [3]  [2] [2]
26  [3] [3]  [3] [3]  [3] [3]
```

しかしながら、できたデータセットはひとつの枠の中に座標（[x座標，y座標]）が入る形になっていて、分割しようと試みましたが、解決方法を見つけることができませんでした。
（「[一つのカラムの中にリストでデータが入っている場合、リストの各要素を分割して新たに列を増やし、各要素をダミー変数化方法はありますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/80570/%E4%B8%80%E3%81%A4%E3%81%AE%E3%82%AB%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%AB%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%A7%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%81%8C%E5%85%A5%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88-%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E5%90%84%E8%A6%81%E7%B4%A0%E3%82%92%E5%88%86%E5%89%B2%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E6%96%B0%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AB%E5%88%97%E3%82%92%E5%A2%97%E3%82%84%E3%81%97-%E5%90%84%E8%A6%81%E7%B4%A0%E3%82%92%E3%83%80%E3%83%9F%E3%83%BC%E5%A4%89%E6%95%B0%E5%8C%96%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95%E3%81%AF%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B?newreg=e83a98fb50eb461cb07c36573a05f0c4)」は一読したものの、原因がわからないでいます）

分割方法（または組み合わせ方や、行毎に計算するなら他の方法があるなど）を何卒ご教示をいただけましたら幸いです。

【こうなってしまいました】

```
         A       B       C
0   [1, 1]  [1, 1]  [1, 1]
1   [1, 1]  [1, 1]  [2, 2]
2   [1, 1]  [1, 1]  [3, 3]
3   [1, 1]  [2, 2]  [1, 1]
4   [1, 1]  [2, 2]  [2, 2]
5   [1, 1]  [2, 2]  [3, 3]
6   [1, 1]  [3, 3]  [1, 1]
7   [1, 1]  [3, 3]  [2, 2]
8   [1, 1]  [3, 3]  [3, 3]
9   [2, 2]  [1, 1]  [1, 1]
10  [2, 2]  [1, 1]  [2, 2]
11  [2, 2]  [1, 1]  [3, 3]
12  [2, 2]  [2, 2]  [1, 1]
13  [2, 2]  [2, 2]  [2, 2]
14  [2, 2]  [2, 2]  [3, 3]
15  [2, 2]  [3, 3]  [1, 1]
16  [2, 2]  [3, 3]  [2, 2]
17  [2, 2]  [3, 3]  [3, 3]
18  [3, 3]  [1, 1]  [1, 1]
19  [3, 3]  [1, 1]  [2, 2]
20  [3, 3]  [1, 1]  [3, 3]
21  [3, 3]  [2, 2]  [1, 1]
22  [3, 3]  [2, 2]  [2, 2]
23  [3, 3]  [2, 2]  [3, 3]
24  [3, 3]  [3, 3]  [1, 1]
25  [3, 3]  [3, 3]  [2, 2]
26  [3, 3]  [3, 3]  [3, 3]
```

失敗したコードは下記です。

```py
# ひとつの線分とあるひとつ座標のすべての組合せの行列を作成する
# 座標サンプル3点
c1=[1,1] 
c2=[2,2]
c3=[3,3]

# 線分と座標のすべての組合せを作成
xy=[c1, c2, c3]
print(xy) 
linedotcomb = [xy, xy, xy]
print(linedotcomb)
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(product(*linedotcomb), columns=list("ABC"))
print(df)


# 分割しようと試みて失敗
for column_name in df:
    print(column_name)
    s = df["A"]
    s.astype(str).str.replace(r'{|}|"', "", regex=True).str.get_dummies(',')
    print(s)
```

Comment: 質問や回答は Markdownで記します。[Markdown や HTML を使用して投稿を書式設定するには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) や [Markdown ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) などを参考にしてみてください

Comment: metropolis様　ありがとうございました！

Comment: oriri様もありがとうございます。勉強させていただきます！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from itertools import product, chain
import pandas as pd

c1 = [1, 1] 
c2 = [2, 2]
c3 = [3, 3]

# 線分と座標のすべての組合せを作成
xy = [c1, c2, c3]
linedotcomb = [xy, xy, xy]
data = [[[i] for i in chain.from_iterable(l)] for l in product(*linedotcomb)]
columns = map(''.join, product('ABC', 'xy'))

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
print(df)

#      Ax   Ay   Bx   By   Cx   Cy
# 0   [1]  [1]  [1]  [1]  [1]  [1]
# 1   [1]  [1]  [1]  [1]  [2]  [2]
# 2   [1]  [1]  [1]  [1]  [3]  [3]
# 3   [1]  [1]  [2]  [2]  [1]  [1]
# 4   [1]  [1]  [2]  [2]  [2]  [2]
# 5   [1]  [1]  [2]  [2]  [3]  [3]

                 :

# 22  [3]  [3]  [2]  [2]  [2]  [2]
# 23  [3]  [3]  [2]  [2]  [3]  [3]
# 24  [3]  [3]  [3]  [3]  [1]  [1]
# 25  [3]  [3]  [3]  [3]  [2]  [2]
# 26  [3]  [3]  [3]  [3]  [3]  [3]
```

Comment: おかげさまで無事行毎の計算をすることができました。【いつかの誰かのための備忘録】なお行毎の計算の事前準備としてAx, Ay, Bx, By, Cx, Cyのobject型 から int型 への変換を「teratail.com/questions/189902」を参照して行い、int型へ変換した後の行毎の計算は「learning-nao.com/?p=3453」を参照致しました。